# How to post a select list's options to an MVC action method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to submit all the items in a select list to an MVC 3 action method.  Here is my Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveList(int SettingID, List<SelectListItem> items)
{
    // blah...
}
```

and here is the simplified version of how I am trying to send the data:

```
var items = $("#listItems > option").map(function ()
{
    var arr = [];
    arr.push({ Value: $(this).val(), Text: $(this).text() });
    return arr;
}).get();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/CompanyAdmin/SaveSettingList/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { items: items, SettingID: SettingID},
    success: function (msg)
    {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

The setting ID param gets populated correctly.  And the List gets populated with the correct AMOUNT of items, but both the Text and Value properties come out as null.

Do I have to install one of the JSON plugins for jQuery to be able to submit an array of items?

**EDIT 1:**

Following Darin Dimitrov's advice I used the stringify method and sent both the SettingID and list of options as JSON.

At first this was not hitting my Action method, so I changed the method to this:

```
public ActionResult SaveList(SaveSettingListModel json)
{}
```

with the param being defined like so: (to match the JSON)

```
public class SaveSettingListModel
{
    public int SettingID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> items { get; set; }
}
```

This now fires the correct method. **However**, the contents of json on the server side are SettingID = 0 (when I verified that it is 2 on the client side), and items = null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try posting them as JSON.

Start by defining a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int SettingID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then modify your controller action to take this view model as argument:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveList(MyViewModel model)
{
    // blah...
}
```

and finally in your script:

```
var items = $('#listItems > option').map(function ()
{
    var arr = [];
    arr.push({ value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text() });
    return arr;
}).get();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/CompanyAdmin/SaveSettingList/', // <-- use an URL Helper to generate this url instead of hardcoding it or you will cry when you deploy your application into a virtual directory
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
        items: items, 
        settingID: SettingID 
    }),
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

And if you want to use the `JSON.stringify` method in legacy browsers in which it is not natively supported make sure you include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script.

All this being said I see where you are going with this controller action and with this AJAX request and I must say that I wouldn't do it this way (send the options in the request). I mean in order to render this view you fetched this list from somewhere? Presumably a datastore? So instead of fighting with the HTML `<form>` (which sends only the selected value of a dropdownlist to the server when submitted) why don't you simply use this very same data store in your `SaveList` action in order to fetch those very same options? This will avoid you round-tripping them and save bandwidth. Don't worry databases are fast. And if they are not in your case simply cache the results of expensive queries.

Completely ignore my previous remark if those options are subject to change on the client side and you want to fetch the new values.

Comment: @Darin, I think you need a toolbar button to post this answer. ;)

Comment: @Neil N, you need a decent/recent browser in which it is natively built-in :-) And for legacy stuff include `json2.js` script as explained in my answer.

Comment: @Kirk Woll, yeah, I actually have a Google Chrome plugin that answers this kind of questions automatically. I have predefined templates. No kidding :-)

Comment: @Darin: you are assuming I am loading the list from a data store.  It is all new items created on the client side, and moved up and down into a specific order.

Comment: @Darin: using your above method I get the following error: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter SettingID"... I am thinking I need to change the param on my action to something like myObject{int SettingID, List<...> items} to match the incoming JSON?

Comment: @Neil N, the `SettingID` variable in your javascript, where does it come from and what's its value? I can't see it defined anywhere. Make sure it is an defined and that it is an integer. And yes you could build a view model and have your controller action take this view model instead of the two action parameters. It will be much more cleaner. I will update my answer.

Comment: the SettingID is an global that is set outside of the method, depending on what Setting is selected in another list on the page. That was the only param that WAS working before.

Comment: @Neil N, I gotta run now but you may take a look at the actual AJAX request sent in FireBug and ensure that the JSON is of the correct format.

Comment: I was missing the 'contentType' line, adding that made everything work fine!  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this it will help you in this case.

http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2009/08/10/mvc-custom-json-binder.aspx